# Lync 2010 UCMA 3.0 SDK -  Call Forwarding

Tags: lync-2010, lync, lync-server-2010

How can I use the Lync API to change current user "call forwarding" option to another SIP or a number?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void OnIncomingAudioVideoCallReceived(object sender, CallReceivedEventArgs<AudioVideoCall> e)
    {
        // Forward incoming Audio calls OR accept call
        try
        {
            _logger.Info("Incoming call from " + e.RemoteParticipant.Uri);
             e.Call.Forward("sip:..");
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioex)
        {
            _logger.Error("Failed forwarding incoming call", ioex);
        }
    }
```